# PopupMenu doesnt pop up onclick

Tags: java, android-studio, onclick, popupmenu

I have this `ImageButton`, which is inside of the `Items` of my `Recyclerview` and which usually should be calling the `method` `showPopup` onclick.
My plan was that when this `Imagebutton` gets clicked there will be a `PopupMenu` from which you can chose to either rename the item or delete it.
But unfortunately things are not working as they are supposed to be.
I appreciate every help.

```
<ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/img_btn_more"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_more"
            android:onClick="showPopup"/>
```

```
public void showPopup(View v){
        PopupMenu popup=new PopupMenu(MyApplication.getAppContext(),v);
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.item1: Toast.makeText(MyApplication.getAppContext()," Random text1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.item2: Toast.makeText(MyApplication.getAppContext()," Random text2",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                    default: return false;
                }
            }
        });
        popup.inflate(R.menu.popup_menu);
        popup.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in a RecyclerView you will have to do this inside the `ViewHolder`
and pass the Context you get when you build the RecyclerViewAdapter

```
holder.*your_image_view*.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
        PopupMenu popup=new PopupMenu(mContext,v);
    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
                case R.id.item1: Toast.makeText(mContext," Random text1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                case R.id.item2: Toast.makeText(mContext," Random text2",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                default: return false;
            }
        }
    });
    popup.inflate(R.menu.popup_menu);
    popup.show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi @Cliz if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.